# Memory Alloc in C to Java

Tags: java, c

I Have a certain C program Now I want to Port it into a Java Program. I got most of the things but I have a code like

```
    tsum=(float *) malloc(cr_nos*sizeof(float));
    rsum=(float *) malloc(cr_nos*sizeof(float));
    ex_sum=(float *) malloc(cr_nos*sizeof(float));
    bsum=(float *) malloc(cr_nos*sizeof(float));
```

Now How Can I allocate this size in a Java Program? cr_nos is an Integer of size (1-10).

Comment: Are you familiar with the java GC and the java variables?

Comment: You don't have to do it manually. Define what *type* you want. The memory will be allocated / deallocated automatically.

Comment: See Here "tsum[n]=tsum[n]+sigma_nought[r][c];" i.e tsum is used as an array.Now How can I Set a size to this array.If i Just Declare "float tsum[];" and use it later IDE initializes it to NULL and when I add Elements it gives me an error;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java equivalent of the code above is:

```
float[] tSum = new float[crCount];
float[] rSum = new float[crCount];
float[] exSum = new float[crCount];
float[] bSum = new float[crCount];
```

... although, in Java, "t", "r", "ex", "b", and "cr" would typically be unabbreviated.

Comment: Will this work because In the code they have multiplied the value of cr_nos with size of Float thats were I am Confused! I have to use as less memory as I can.

Comment: @user2983451 Yes it will work. In C, you have to multiply by the size to get the correct amount of memory, in Java (and C++ FTR) the multiplication is performed implicitly when you specify `new float`

Answer (score 2):

Java and C are very different when it comes to memory management. You don't need to specifically allocate or deallocate memory - just create the objects you need and let Java do the work for you. I suspect there'll be a lot of boilerplate in C that will simply disappear when you are done.

Comment: While you don't need to deallocate memory, I would consider the `new` keyword in Java to be an example of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Except that you don't really have the choice not to use `new`. The language is designed to allocate dynamically, and makes you type `new` mainly for fun.

Comment: "The language is designed to allocate dynamically" You just proved my point for me.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart But it isn't `new` that does it for you. Objects will get dynamically allocated. `new` is largely syntactic baggage.